# Intermittent peer not authenticated - when trusting all the certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate

One more to the list of the mysterious "peer not authenticated".

I have an apache httpclient using 4.2 lib.  I have explicitly set to trust all certificates in the code.
I have a Tomcat server (JRE 1.7U45), serving the requests on Linux.  The server has a self signed certificate.

Client side code:

```
private DefaultHttpClient getHttpsClient() {
    try {

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        final SSLSocketFactory sf;
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
            }
        } }, new SecureRandom());

        sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext,
                SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme(url.getScheme(), url.getPort(), sf));

        ClientConnectionManager cm = new BasicClientConnectionManager(
                registry);

        return new MyDefaultHttpClient(cm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new MyDefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

This error is only seen intermittently on "Solaris 5.10" (32 bit JRE 1.7.0u45) clients talking to the server.
Sometime, the request on the same box go thru fine, but at other times, this just throws "Peer Not Authenticate"
I have other flavors of OS clients, where the call is going thru just fine.
Would any of have any suggestions/pointers to look into this issue?

More Update:
Ran the ssl debug on the server and we see that intermittently, it throws
http-bio-8443-exec-7, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Invalid Padding length: 105
http-bio-8443-exec-7, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Invalid Padding length: 105

Comment: Why was this question demoted?  This is a very strange issue, where httpclient is failing when I am trusting all the certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due the following bug in JRE 1.7 http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8013059

Also, the apache httpclient 4.2 added to the confusion, where it masking the actual exception thrown instead throwing the generic "Peer not authenticated"

In the server.xml of tom-cat, for connector element, add the cipher attribute with a list of non-DH ciphers
E.g. 
ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"

This solved the issue.
Hope this is useful to someone.

Thanks